# Compare files with a zip list and figure out if it is larger

Tags: python, list, copy

I want to compare the files of two zip folders.
Copy only if the magnitude is greater when there is already a zip at the end when missing an equal name, copy the file.
Only Name is compared not a date: es--> Campobasso[CB]-Molise

Folder DirTemp ZIP:
Campobasso[CB]-Molise__02-02-2016.zip

Folder DirArc ZIP:
Foggia[FG]-Puglia__22-01-2016.zip
Roma[RM]-Lazio__20-01-2016.zip

Folder DirArcScartati, 
They are the zip that if found and are smaller are put another folder

This is my code, but work partially, I can not to copy the file (if not exist) at the end of the control, with list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import os,glob,shutil

DirTemp = "/var/www/vhosts/anon_ftp/incoming/"
DirArc = "/var/www/vhosts/settings/BackupDTT/"
DirArcScartati = "/var/www/vhosts/settings/BackupDTT_scartati/"
ExtFile = ".zip"


def ControlFile():
    # Controllo i nuovi file zip
    listnew=[]
    #print "Avvio copia"
    for name in glob.glob(DirTemp + "*" + ExtFile):
        listnew.append((name.replace(DirTemp,"").replace(ExtFile,"").split("__")[0],name))
        #print "Nome: "+ str(listnew) 


    for oldname in glob.glob(DirArc + "*" + ExtFile):
        #print "Setting Esistente: "+oldname 
        namesplit = oldname.replace(DirArc,"").replace(ExtFile,"").split("__")[0] 
        for newname in listnew:
            #print "New Nome: "+str(newname[0]) 
            print namesplit
            if namesplit == newname[0]:
                if os.path.getsize(newname[1]) >= os.path.getsize(oldname):
                    print ("trasferire file" + newname[1] + " >>> " + oldname)
                    shutil.copy2(newname[1],DirArc)
                    os.remove(oldname)
                    #os.remove(newname[1])
                    break
                elif os.path.getsize(newname[1]) <= os.path.getsize(oldname):
                    print ("File più piccolo---\nFileNuovo: " + str(os.path.getsize(newname[1])) + " FileVecchio: " + str(os.path.getsize(oldname)))
                    shutil.copy2(newname[1],DirArcScartati)
                    #os.remove(newname[1])
                    break
        else:
            for newname in listnew:
                print ("Nuova città trasferisco il file: " + newname[1])
                shutil.copy2(newname[1],DirArc)
                #os.remove(newname[1])
                break

ControlFile()
```

Comment: Note: Your `else` statement is not aligned correctly, I am guessing it should be under `if namesplit == newname[0]:`

Comment: if I remove the file after copying stops the code
Nuova città trasferisco il file: /var/www/vhosts/anon_ftp/incoming/Campobasso[CB]-Molise__02-02-2016.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./copy.py", line 45, in <module>
    ControlFile()
  File "./copy.py", line 27, in ControlFile
    if os.path.getsize(newname[1]) >= os.path.getsize(oldname):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/vhosts/anon_ftp/incoming/Campobasso[CB]-Molise__02-02-2016.zip'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach might be a bit easier to follow:

```
def get_file_dictionary(folder):
    """ Return a dictionary of zip files in the given folder as tuples in the form: (basename, full path, size) """
    return {os.path.splitext(os.path.split(x)[1])[0].split('__')[0] : (x, os.path.getsize(x)) for x in glob.glob(folder + '*.zip')}

DirTemp = "/var/www/vhosts/italysat.eu/anon_ftp/incoming/"
DirArc = "/var/www/vhosts/italysat.eu/settings.italysat.eu/BackupDTT/"
DirArcScartati = "/var/www/vhosts/italysat.eu/settings.italysat.eu/BackupDTT_scartati/"    

incoming = get_file_dictionary(DirTemp)
existing = get_file_dictionary(DirArc)

for base_name_inc, (full_name_inc, size_inc) in incoming.items():
    try:
        full_name_exist, size_exist = existing[base_name_inc]

        if size_inc > size_exist:
            print "Transfer {} -> {}".format(full_name_inc, full_name_exist)
            os.remove(full_name_exist)
            shutil.copy2(full_name_inc, full_name_exist)
        else:
            discard = os.path.join(DirArcScartati, os.path.split(full_name_inc)[1])
            print "Discard {} -> {}".format(full_name_inc, discard)
            shutil.copy2(full_name_inc, discard)
    except KeyError, e:
        new_entry = os.path.join(DirArc, os.path.split(full_name_inc)[1])
        print "Transfer new {} -> {}".format(full_name_inc, new_entry)

    os.remove(full_name_inc)
```

It first creates to dictionaries containing all of the entries in the incoming folder and the archive folder. It then iterates over the incoming dictionary to see if an entry is in the archive. If it is, it checks the two sizes, if not it copies the new entry.

The dictionaries are stored with the key being your base name (without dates) and the values being the full path name and the file size.

Comment: Thanks this works fine, the line after:
`print "Transfer new {} -> {}". format (full_name_inc, new_entry)`
  added
`shutil.copy2 (full_name_inc, new_entry)`
to transfer the new file.

Comment: Great I'm glad it worked. I wasn't 100% sure what you needed, but I felt this approach made it much easier to understand and adapt to your needs. Don't forget to click the grey tick next to the answer to accept the solution when you are finished.